# Crm 2011 QueryExpression DateTime Equal Condition

Tags: c#, datetime, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to retrieve Invoices which is created 2 years ago with QueryExpression (day and month parts have to match). I updated some Invoice records' createdon fields in Sql to make them match with current date. Then I wrote the code which is shown below but I got no record.

```
       DateTime _2YearsAgo = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2);

       QueryExpression getInvoices= new QueryExpression("invoice");
       getInvoices.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
       getInvoices.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
       getInvoices.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.Equal, _2YearsAgo);

       EntityCollection invoices = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(getInvoices);
```

I also tried to update 'createdon' field value considering time part and convert DateTime parameter to ShortDateString and UTC time.

Comment: Do you get any results without the condition ?

Comment: Yes I do, nothing wrong with data

Comment: the query should work, if you want to be sure to pull some data, create 2 conditions(before and after with some days apart)

Comment: While I was trying the approach you suggest (There are Onbefore and OnAfter condition operators). I realize that 'On' operator is exactly what I'm looking for. Now It works fine, thanks for help.

Comment: right, On operator is the one to be used with datetime, good you figured out